# Why do I keep getting an error with the return statement

Tags: c#

I keep getting an error with the return statement.

Write a C# program to get the absolute difference between n and 51. If n is greater than 51 return triple the absolute difference.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Calculations(5));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static double Calculations(double n)
    {
        double diff;
            
        if (n < 51)
        {
            diff = Math.Abs(51) - Math.Abs(n);
        }
        else if (n > 51)
        {
            diff = (Math.Abs(51) - Math.Abs(n)) * 3;
        }                     

        return diff;
    }       
}
```

Comment: It's important that you say exactly what the error is, not just *"an error"*.

Answer (score 6):

Diff is not guaranteed to be defined since you are using an else if. If you change that to an else, all code paths will define diff and you shouldn't have an issue. This should be the same as changing the else if to n >= 51.

Right now there is a possible code path (n=51), where diff will not be initialized.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize your return value of `diff`.

```cs
double diff = 0d;
```

Comment: He could also add an `else` block to match all values of `diff`.

Comment: Absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an initial value to diff and it will return no errors

Comment: What would this initial value be? 15? 42? -90?

Comment: initialize it to zero value diff = 0;

Comment: so that whenever this function returns zero means that n is equal to 51 there is no difference